# Could not Connect to MySQL: Access Denied for user 'alapetz'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

Looked around this website a lot and still couldn't find an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code that I am having problems with:

```
//This file contains the database access information.

//This file also establishes a connection to MySQL

//and selects the database

//Set the database access information as constants:
DEFINE ('DB_USER','alapetz');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD','******');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST','localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'alapetz');

//Make the connection

$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .
mysqli_connect_error() );

?>
```

Tried a lot of solutions like "create another user" or "set permissions" but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.